# How to add a variable in javascript?

Tags: javascript

```
var count=0 ;
for(var x=0; x<data_len; x++)
{
     count = count + num_arr[x];
}
// alert(count);
```

If `count = 352` I want to add 3+5+2 which is 10 and then 1+0 which is 1.

Comment: Your array must be of numeric strings, not integers.  use [`parseInt(num_arr[x], 10)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) to get a proper integer.

Comment: Indeed, your question is a bit unclear - too bad, that was an interesting one. I wonder whether my answer is right or wrong by the way, let me know :) ⇨ http://stackoverflow.com/a/22164643/1636522.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function sumParts(x) {
    var sumX = 0;
    var strX = x.toString();
    var arrX = strX.split("");
    for (a = 0; a < arrX.length; a++) {
        sumX += parseInt(arrX[a], 10);
    };
    return sumX;
}
y = sumParts(count);
z = sumParts(y);
// y = 10; (3 + 5 + 2)
// z = 1; (1 + 0)
```

And, I believe (untested), if the return was changed to `return sumParts(sumX)`, it would continue until it was a single digit integer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer..but I am getting value of -2 OR -1 from z depend on count

Comment: sumX returns -1 inside for loop

Comment: sumX += parseInt(arrX.indexOf(a), 10);   Here no need to use index i get it through  sumX += parseInt(arrX[a], 10) ; Thanks for the solution

Answer (score 0):

You have an array of strings, not numbers. You can convert them to numbers with:

```
count = count + +num_arr[x];
```

The second `+` is the unary plus operator, and will cast `num_arr[x]` to a number.

If your numbers are all integers, you can use:

```
count = count + parseInt(num_arr[x], 10);
```

or (if you have floats):

```
count = count + parseFloat(num_arr[x]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert `count` into a string :

```
var count = 352;
count += ''; // makes a string : "352"
while (count.length > 1) {
    count = Function('return ' + count.split('').join('+') + ';')() + '';
}
```

This part :

```
Function('return ' + count.split('').join('+') + ';')
```

Gives successively :

```
function () { return 3+5+2; }
function () { return 1+0; }
```